# Book recommendation for history of spaceflight

Tags: history, reference-request

I am interested in the history of space-flight and was wondering if anyone had any good book suggestions. I have no scientific background, but am more interested in the science behind the space missions than the personalities of the astronauts/cosmonauts etc. Thanks

Comment: I am using an old phone so can't post a link but check out the history section in the "references" question on the meta site.

Comment: From Sputnik to space ports in 55 pages: [The History of Spaceflight](http://www.americanbar.org/content/dam/aba/administrative/science_technology/ch2historyofspaceflight.authcheckdam.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this is the resource](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/250/6750) Organic Marble mentioned in the comment. Somewhere down the answer there is a section *History books and collections*. A couple more things I can think of:

- *It's ONLY Rocket Science: An Introduction in Plain English* is a nice read on pretty much everything involved in space missions and
  astronautics. It is not really focused on history. But when
  discussing topics (which it does in a "friendly" way, as title
  suggests) it uses historic examples in many cases.
- If you are interested in Apollo missions you may find interesting
  topics on technology and design processes in *Digital Apollo: Human
  and Machine in Spaceflight*. Though it might not be exactly what you
  are looking for now.

I know these aren't books, but still for future reference I would
   recommend two Wiki sources:

- For a short overwiew I like Wikipedia's [History of spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_spaceflight),
  with links pointing you to more specific topics.
- And if you want a chronological walk through the events Wikipedia's [Timeline of spaceflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_spaceflight) is a good place to check out.

If you can provide some feedback I may be able to give you more recommendations.